# running librosa & numba on raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, numba, librosa

I am trying to run librosa on my raspberry pi 3. 
After hours of searching through the internet I was finally able to install it but it still throws an error when I try to import it. First, I had problems to install the dependency `llvmlite`. I finally installed it with the following code: `conda install -c numba llvmlite`. I use python 3.4 build with miniconda.

After llvmlite was installed I was able to install librosa with `pip` (not possible with conda)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install librosa
Collecting librosa
Using cached https://www.piwheels.hostedpi.com/simple/librosa/librosa-
0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: resampy>=0.1.2 in 
./miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from librosa)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.13.0 in 
...
Installing collected packages: librosa
Successfully installed librosa-0.5.1
```

Apparently librosa is installed.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. 
You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=
(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable 
this warning.
anaconda-client (1.0.2)
audioread (2.1.5)
awscli (1.11.170)
boto3 (1.4.7)
botocore (1.7.28)
clyent (0.4.0)
colorama (0.3.7)
conda (3.16.0)
conda-env (2.4.2)
Cython (0.27.1)
decorator (4.1.2)
docutils (0.14)
jmespath (0.9.3)
joblib (0.11)
librosa (0.5.1)
llvmlite (0.7.0.dev0+21.gcda19bd.dirty)
mock (2.0.0)
numba (0.35.0)
numpy (1.13.3)
pbr (3.1.1)
Pillow (2.9.0)
pip (9.0.1)
protobuf (3.4.0)
pyasn1 (0.3.7)
PyAudio (0.2.11)
pycosat (0.6.1)
pycrypto (2.6.1)    
python-dateutil (2.6.1)
pytz (2015.4)
PyYAML (3.12)
requests (2.7.0)
resampy (0.2.0)
rsa (3.4.2)
s3transfer (0.1.11)
scikit-learn (0.18.2)
scipy (0.19.1)
setuptools (18.1)
six (1.11.0)
tensorflow (1.1.0)
Werkzeug (0.12.2)
wheel (0.30.0)
```

Trying to import librosa throws the following error though:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python
Python 3.4.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Aug 21 2015, 00:53:08) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import librosa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/librosa/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/librosa/core/__init__.py", line 108, in <module>
    from .time_frequency import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/librosa/core/time_frequency.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ..util.exceptions import ParameterError
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/librosa/util/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from . import decorators
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/librosa/util/decorators.py", line 67, in <module>
    from numba.decorators import jit as optional_jit
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numba/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .special import typeof, prange
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numba/special.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .parfor import prange
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numba/parfor.py", line 20, in <module>
    from numba import array_analysis, postproc, typeinfer
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numba/array_analysis.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numba import ir, analysis, types, config, cgutils, typing
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numba/cgutils.py", line 22, in <module>
    true_bit = bool_t(1)
TypeError: 'IntType' object is not callable
>>>
```

Trying to import numba throws the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python
Python 3.4.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Aug 21 2015, 00:53:08) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numba
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numba/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .special import typeof, prange
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numba/special.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .parfor import prange
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numba/parfor.py", line 20, in <module>
    from numba import array_analysis, postproc, typeinfer
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numba/array_analysis.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numba import ir, analysis, types, config, cgutils, typing
  File "/home/pi/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numba/cgutils.py", line 22, in <module>
    true_bit = bool_t(1)
TypeError: 'IntType' object is not callable
>>>
```

Has anyone a clue what the problem could be?
I am grateful for any hints or tips. 
Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of writing, the latest Raspbian release has llvm-3.8, so per [this github comment](https://github.com/numba/llvmlite/issues/234#issuecomment-281179496) you need to install llvmlite v0.15.0 with numba v0.30.1. If you're on a different llvm then you will need to explore what versions of llvmlite and numba to use with that version of llvm.
Here are the commands that got me set up to get a successful `import librosa`:

```
sudo apt install libblas-dev llvm python3-pip python3-scipy
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 env
source env/bin/activate
pip install llvmlite==0.15.0
pip install numba==0.30.1
pip install librosa
```

Note I'm using virtualenv and dragging in scipy and numpy from the system packages, otherwise it's hard to get the fortran & c dependencies right plus those take ages to compile on a RPi. If you want to install system-wide then drop the 2nd and 3rd line and put `sudo` in front of the `pip` commands. I've also frozen my requirements in this [requirements.txt](https://gist.github.com/matthewberryman/83d7dedb14a85b81866b486b4e5fe02e) file so if you download that then you can run a single command `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: I tried this but I get the following:  error:root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sudo pip3 install llvmite==0.15.0
Downloading/unpacking llvmite==0.15.0
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement llvmite==0.15.0
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for llvmite==0.15.0
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log

Comment: Looks like it's simply a typo, it should be llvmlite==0.15.0 but you've written llvmite==0.15.0

Comment: @MatthewBerryman I'm trying to do this on my Rpi3 and I get the following error: Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-DApH0j/llvmlite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-UCWh1n-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-DApH0j/llvmlite/

Comment: @SreehariR very hard to say without the error log from pip. Can you paste here (or if it won't fit, paste elsewhere and link)? Just checking you've run the command `sudo apt install libblas-dev llvm python3-pip python3-scipy` to install llvm? You may need to add llvm-dev to that list of packages.

Comment: Ok I'll attach a google docs link, also its worth noting that I'm not using a virtualenv (I don't know if that changes things)

Comment: Here is the docs link: https://docs.google.com/document/d/16QU9fYsA9gKTBDp19B2VGfD7_S9tZVoe2-LFRAXq-sk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @SreehariR a couple of things: (1) if you're not using virtualenv then you need to run `sudo pip3 install ...` to install system-wide (for python3) or if you want to use python2 then `sudo pip install ...` for each of the packages. However (2) that unhelpful error message you're seeing is actually caused when pip can't connect to the server to download the packages (pip3 is a little bit more helpful in that it tells you what server is down). I have reported the server problem to the person who maintains it and will let you know when it's back up.

Comment: @MatthewBerryman Thank you for filing the issue and notifying me! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @SreehariR I haven't heard back from the person who runs the server but tested just then and the pip install worked again for me, so it seems it's fixed.

Comment: @MatthewBerryman I was able to run the first line. However when trying to run the command sudo pip install numba==0.30.1 I got the same error. I updated the docs link with the error message: https://docs.google.com/document/d/16QU9fYsA9gKTBDp19B2VGfD7_S9tZVoe2-LFRAXq-sk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159954/discussion-between-matthew-berryman-and-sreehari-r).

Answer (score 3):

`sudo pip install librosa==0.4.2` worked for me. There was warning yet works fine on Raspberry pi3 (OS:raspbian-jessie)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @MatthewBerryman, you got me over the hump!  On the newest Raspian release (stretch) I was successful with the following after several hours of frustration of trying to get librosa installed on Raspian jessie (which my RPi3 came with).  Having said this, the following procedure may also work with jessie.

First, update your system's package list and upgrade all your installed packages to their latest versions with the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Install Python science stack:

```
sudo pip3 install numpy --upgrade 
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
```

(Also seems to install matplotlib, scipy)

```
sudo apt-get install python3-sklearn
```

Then, install the low-level virtual machine, LLVM (per @MatthewBerryman, I used llvm 3.8 and llvmlite 0.15.0, and not the newest combination where I couldn't find the packages.)  After installing llvm-3.8, a symbolic link needs to be defined before installing llvmlite.

```
sudo apt-get install llvm-3.8
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-config-3.8 /usr/bin/llvm-config
sudo pip3 install llvmlite==0.15.0
sudo pip3 install numba==0.32.0
```

Numba is 0.32.0 because if it's the newest (0.36), it will not import because of an llvm mismatch, and if it's a lower version, the librosa install will upgrade it to the newest version.

Finally, install librosa:

```
sudo pip3 install librosa
```

However, when trying to import librosa, it still throws and error, namely

```
ImportError: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Googling this error indicated this would fix it:

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

And it did; however, I have no idea why.

To summarize, this procedure installs librosa, and there is no error when trying this:

```
...$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04)
...
>>>import librosa
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have previously installed packages, either reboot with a fresh copy of OS or create a virtual environment, as suggested by others. Creating virtual env did not work at the first try for me, you might want to reboot to a fresh copy.

Then install virtualenv and create a new virtualenv.

Activate the virtualenv using python3.

```
sudo apt-get install llvm
```

You should get llvm 7.0.x

Then install a compatible llvmlite - this works for 7.0. Get the path by typing `which llvm-config` In my case it was /usr/bin/llvm-config

```
LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config pip3 install llvmlite==0.32
```

install dependencies

```
pip3 install numpy==1.16.1 numba==0.49
```

```
pip3 install librosa
```

If you get an error after trying to import librosa due to numpy, update dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

Credits to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ye96YO-lz_4) tutorial

Answer (score 0):

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111697/unable-to-pip-install-librosa-in-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-raspbian-stretch

Anyone can refer this link , I got a successful install in RPi 3 B+ with Raspbian Buster OS