# Installing librosa on a Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, installation, librosa, llvmlite

I've tried installing librosa on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. I have referred to other links regarding this issue as well including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751140/running-librosa-numba-on-raspberry-pi-3) and [this](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2428) but the errors still kept coming.

As of now, I'm stuck with:

> libllvmlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I checked the git repository of llvmlite and looked for the file in

> ./ ffi / libllvmlite.so
>   ./ llvmlite / bindings / lbllvmlite.so

because that's what I've gathered in the links I provided but the file isn't even there.

I reinstalled my Raspbian OS one time and proceeded to try again and install librosa and got another error regarding something like it requires LLVM 5.0?

I also tried installing it with conda but when I try to, I also get an error

> The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
>   • librosa
>   • python 3.6*

Have you any success with installing librosa on a Raspberry Pi 3? If so, how did you do it?