# Installing librosa on raspberry pi3

Tags: python, scipy, raspberry-pi3, librosa, llvmlite

I am currently trying to install librosa and after days trying to figure it out I'm now quite helpless. I have tried several solutions, such as [running librosa & numba on raspberry pi 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751140/running-librosa-numba-on-raspberry-pi-3)
and also https://stackoverflow.com/a/52941768/10499025

Neither **pip** nor **conda** nor **clone git** would function properly, also downloading the **librosa zip** and installing it manually with

```
python setup.py install
```

did not work out; 
I tried it with and without **virtualenv**,

my guess is that the problem is something with the sidepackages, So I tried **installing the side packages seperately**. That only worked out with git clone and I do not know for sure if I installed them properly. Although that did not solve all of my problems, it seemed to solve the **building wheels** problem for scipy and numpy, but still llvmlite was not working.

Moreover I also tried to **update** my **setuptools**, **pip** and python in general, also tried pip/pip3 and tried mentioning the **--user**. Everything without any effect.

I understand that I need certain versions of the packages for librosa in order to function, and I guess my problem is something with building wheels and finding packages, or at least the right versions of these packages.

the packages I am struggeling with most are **SCIPY, NUMPY, SCIKIT-LEARN and LLVMLITE**.

Anyway, I think I confused myself rather than help understand it. So, as I said before I am thankful for any advice, insight etc..!

So, here are my error codes:

When I try installing librosa I always get:

with virtualenv:

```
sudo apt install libblas-dev llvm python3-pip python3-scipy
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 env
source env/bin/activate
pip install llvmlite==0.15.0
pip install numba==0.30.1
pip install librosa
```

error:

```
Command "/home/pi/flaskenv/bin/python -u - c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-iYvjRD/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-7L25tV/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pi/flaskenv/include/site/python2.7/scipy" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-iYvjRD/scipy/
```

--> full error code:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dHq0S227vld4iJ7H2SgaDJ2jlD95bZUKqkUH4VhrS2U/edit?usp=sharing

without virtualenv:

```
sudo pip install librosa

Failed building wheel for scipy
Failed cleaning build dir for scipy
Failed building wheel for llvmlite
```

error:

`Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-AUlqg0/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-44B19L-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-AUlqg0/scipy/

`
--> full error code:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pPs6JEqeJ2uS1xWCg8d_dqsbJ6Tgh2EO-eB5aUOYU7I/edit?usp=sharing

installing with **conda** fails always because of audioread --> audioread is not found

So right now, I am thinking that maybe I should install numpy and scipy manually before librosa, than using this lines to get the right versions of llvmlite and numba

```
udo apt install libblas-dev llvm python3-pip python3-scipy
pip install llvmlite==0.15.0
pip install numba==0.30.1
```

and then trying to install librosa? Would that work? Am I missing something really important? 
Already thank you for reading through this haha! And looking forward to any solutions!!
Lola

PS: I am working on a raspberrypi3 with noobs

Comment: There should be more error output before the line(s) you have copied.

Comment: yes, there's a lot more, but I guess I need to put it in an extra file... just give me a moment

Comment: I have edited my question, it includes now two google doc files

Comment: are you able to install numpy, scipy, scikit, libblas etc. on RPi3 ?